# html markup in Play Framework messages

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using the Internationalisation messages file in Play. In my messages.en file I have:

```
support.msg=Click here to contact <a href="support.html">support</a>
```

but this gets output as

```
&lt;a href=&quot;support.html&quot;&gt;support&lt;/a&gt;
```

Is it possible to escape html in messages.en file so they are output 'as is'

Comment: More challenging question is how to avoid hardcoding the URL and make it this way: support.msg=Click here to contact <a href="@routes.SomeController.support()">support</a>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, Play! automatically escapes strings used in a view. If you'd like to output raw text (including the HTML), wrap the variable in `Html()`.

[Example from the docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates):

```
<p>
  @Html(article.content)    
</p>
```

Comment: Also, you might be better off to leave markup out of the messages, and just place the text that you need i18n on. That way, if the link changes or you change how the "support" functions, you only have to change it in your routes.

Comment: De facto, for frequently changing labels it would be best to place them in the database, so you could change it without redeploying whole application, hint: using common cache you'll avoid frequent DB querying as well.