# Creating html link programmatically in Play Framework

Tags: html, scala, playframework

I aim to create a link programmatically in play framework. The function getAuthor gets a list, and returns a string as below:

- if list is empty, an empty string is shown
- if there is 1 item in the list, return a string (first element)
- if more than an item is in the list, 1 string and a "more" icon will be shown as a lookup to see the other items
  However, when my code is run in browser, the link's html code is shown in the browser instead of the intended icon (more.png) as below:
  [link's html shown in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Op0.png)

My code is as following. Please advise the best way to generate the link.

```
@getAuthor(authors: Seq[Author]) = @{
if(authors.isEmpty) ""
else if (authors.length==1) authors(0).name
else authors(0).name + "<a href=\"#\"><img border=\"0\" alt=\"more\" src=\""+routes.Assets.versioned("images/more.png")+"\" width=\"25\" height=\"25\">"
}

....
        @books.map { book: Book =>
        <tr>
            <td>@book.name</td>
            <td>@book.publishDate</td>
            <td>@(getAuthor(book.authors))</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: I used @Html(getAuthor(book.authors)) to solve the issue. Now the link is shown as expected. I learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565632/html-markup-in-play-framework-messages)

Answer (score 0):

have you seen the documentation about reverse routing? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing

you should be able to do something like:

```
<a href=@routes.MyController.myMethod("someArg")>Click me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Not sure if you read my question. I need an icon link that points to # ( the href is equal to '#' and I will add a functionality to the link later through JQuery) and the link is added after the first element in the list, if there is more than one element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to have a list of urls, but each are customized based on the items in the list? If so, it is easy!:

1. A loop to go over the list
2. Within the body of the loop, and iteration to create the url.

For example, if I have the the list of authors in the list of books, in my scala.html file I would add the following in my `scala.html` file:

```
@for(book: Book <- books){ 
  for(author: Author <- book.authors){
    <a href="@author.name">@author.name </a>
  }
}
```